# Typescript: how to generate Tuple out of Array Tree recursively?

Tags: typescript, recursion, type-conversion, tuples

I have the following data structure:

```
const data = [{
   value: 'value',
   label: 'Label',
   children: [
    {
       value: 'value.1',
       label: 'Label.1',
       children: [{
         value: 'value.1.1',
         label: 'Label.1.1',
       }],
    }, 
    {
       value: 'value.2',
       label: 'Label.2',
       children: [{
         value: 'value.2.1',
         label: 'Label.2.1',
       }],
    }
   ],
},{
   value: 'value2',
   label: 'Label2',
}] as const;
```

My aim is to generate the following tuple base on `data` with (editor) auto-complete:

`[parent, children, childrenOfChildren]`

with:

```
parent = 'value' | 'value2'; 
children = if parent === 'value' ? 'value.1' | 'value.2'; // The comment below explain the flow
// ['value' | 'value2'] > 'value' > ['value', 'value.1' | 'value.2'] > 'value.1' > ['value', 'value.1', 'value.1.1' | 'value.1.2'] > 'value.1.1' > ['value', 'value.1', 'value.1.1']
...
```

So the tuple should be **dynamic** based on the **depth** of the *children array* in the object representing the *key* in **data**.
Picking `'value'` will look something like this:

`['value' | 'value2', 'value.1' | 'value.2' ]` where `'value.1' | 'value.2'` can be chosed from.

Picking 'value' and then 'value.1' will be:

`['value', 'value.1', or (value.1).children.value ]`.

What I've done so far:

1. Convert data to const: `data = [...] as const;`
2. Generic type

```
declare const generateTuple: <T extends Record<K, PropertyKey | T[]>, K extends keyof T>(
  objArray: readonly T[],
  property: K,
) => [T[K]];
```

This successfully generates type for the given key, but not for the depth. I couldn't find a way to generate the return tuple type recursively:

```
[T[K], generateTuple(T[K]['children'], k)]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&dtPR=57747&install-plugin=playground-dt-review#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0bh1cQAXlAAG0AN6KEqgHQMaDsSD5UAAck53Mg-N4bJKjGkMD5-OeDCl0FF4pMamiTk4fMZytArPZeqFPJlBsgAQAjEq9ezJdKBXKFWaLZaVZjuOrNbqnSVjUauTyzQ6xZ6JfKbbKQ9B-ebA06AL4AXWjJRj-G1Hst3oFxoCACZHZbrdAZXaYDm83qNC63Uy006M4LfSbswHtfnw0Xwznm5744nQDHlQnFMm03XjbnEwX2wrx0O42JhBSqQBuYLcSCwRh9Rc0Zgo751SA4dgLXmgAA8OHBqwUPGEj3X8DI3DPAGl%20LQ2BtUHgX5A8KAAB9vEZOMAD5%20BfK8b24YR4j-IkcFAgAKcV4GkAArCoyDIJg%20UmbhGmgf8cBA6MCE-b5vz5N9FAASlAOlQJKRkSJfOM4xXRRtzQfQaAZXdOH3BQjxPJCaVQBh%20HrYV%20VoziVEZaSeX5QDMwbXM5yYpSRVAJjFONUU1OFB1VO00tNKMv1zV0pltMMsyo0sk1TRMoCHPMmz3OsvS7KkrNHK8-k4yAA)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your example. If you choose `value` as the key the tuple should look like `['value', 'value.1' | 'value.2' ]`. But why not `['value' | 'value2', 'value.1' | 'value.2' ]`? There are two top level objects in the array. Can you add more examples with expected outputs?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 top-level objects (this can be more). But in this case, I am choosing only one: `value`. So at this point, the choice is already made. But in a normal case (when nothing is chosen), that would be what you propose.

Comment: *"But in a normal case (when nothing is chosen), that would be what you propose"* what do you mean?

Comment: Your `generateTuple` is a function,  not a type.  It can’t appear inside a type expression.  Presumably you want a union of tuples representing all possible paths through that structure.  In any case please [edit] the code to be a [mre] with no pseudo code (e.g., `[…]`) and with a clear expected output type.

Comment: I've added a `playground` link to the description. I hope it will make things clearer. by the way `[T[K], generateTuple(T[K]['children'], k)]` is just an idea.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAy3Xm) work for you?  It takes `typeof data` and transforms it into the union of all paths down through it, which looks like `[] | ["value"] | ["value", "value.1"] | ["value", "value.1", "value.1.1"] | ["value", "value.2"] | ["value", "value.2", "value.2.1"] | ["value2"]`.  If that's right, I can write up an answer; if it's not right, please edit the question to clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, if you have anything in the playground link that clarifies the question, it should be in the plaintext of your question as well.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your suggestion. It does propose a good solution. That is almost what I am aiming for, with the only difference that `values` should not be merged. So each next step should only propose children present in its parent: `['value', 'value.1' | 'value.2']`.

Comment: I don't understand, I don't intend to "merge" anything, nor do I know what `values` is supposed to be.  If you could show me, with code, how my suggestion fails for your use case, then maybe I can address it.  Otherwise I am relying on your verbal descriptions alone and I'm not following.

Comment: I just posted the image on the answer. I hope it makes it understandable. In the case of the picture, only `value.1` and `value.2` should be present in the suggestion proposal.

Comment: I can't put a picture in my IDE to test it.  Please review what constitutes a [mre], as well as the [guidance on images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: The tuple type in my suggested solution is essentially correct, and it doesn't accept `["value", "value"]`; observe [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLlYZm). If you are saying that IntelliSense suggests something invalid, that's out of scope for the question as asked.  If you want to post a followup question about IntelliSense (after searching for duplicates) maybe someone could answer it.  If you want to see different behavior, could you be explicit about what you're looking for?  What type or union of types should `DataPaths<typeof data>` be?

Comment: Note: the IntelliSense issue you're having is a known missing feature in TS, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38603.

Comment: Exactly! I was wondering why it was merging values although the code is correct: `[T["value"], ...DataPaths<T["children"]>]`. Perfect, you can add your proposition I'll mark it as **the** answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that you have a value `data` of type extending `Data` as defined by:

```
type Data = readonly DataElement[];

interface DataElement {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  children?: Data;
}
```

And you'd like to define a type function like `type DataPaths<T extends Data>` that evaluates to a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) representing every possible path of `value` properties down through the tree.  For `data` as given in your question, this should look something like:

```
type ValidPaths = DataPaths<typeof data>
// type ValidPaths = [] | ["value"] | ["value", "value.1"] | 
// ["value", "value.1", "value.1.1"] | ["value", "value.2"] | 
// ["value", "value.2", "value.2.1"] | ["value2"]
```

It's not clear to me whether you actually only want paths that go all the way down to the [leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology) nodes of the tree structure, or if you're okay with paths that end before the leaves.  I'm going with the latter, so that's why the above includes `["value"]` as well as the empty tuple `[]`.

---

Here's one way to implement it:

```
type DataPaths<T extends Data | undefined> = 
  [T] extends [Data] ? DataElementPaths<T[number]> : []

type DataElementPaths<T extends DataElement> = [] | (
  T extends DataElement ? [T["value"], ...DataPaths<T["children"]>] : never
)
```

The idea is that `DataPaths` acts upon a (possibly `undefined`) array of `DataElement` types, while `DataElement` acts upon a `DataElement` type (or a union of them).  The `DataPaths<T>` type is implemented to either return `DataElementPaths` for all array elements of `T` if it's an array or the empty tuple otherwise (if it's `undefined`).

And `DataElementPaths` just prepends (via [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)) the `value` property of the `DataElement` to the result of [recursively](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) evaluating `DataPaths` for the `children` property.

Note that the empty tuple is unioned into the result of `DataElementPaths` no matter what (as `[] |` ); it is this which allows partial paths; if you removed that then you'd only get paths to leaves.

And also note that in order for unions of inputs to become unions of outputs, this is implemented as a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types); hence the `T extends DataElement ? ... : never`.  It seems like a no-op (we already know that `T extends DataElement`) but without it you'd only get a single tuple and not a union out.

---

And you can verify that the implementation does produce the desired type for `ValidPaths`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgCYEM4oQXgQbQN6gIIBuKANgK4CmAXAgOSmVX0A0hCZKARlWXfQAyPPmw5gAFgEsySAE5UodHByIEQRTSXLUBTagDoAjGI1bOI-g2G8yx0+YSSZ8xcvWOi+2g2-H77GaOXLYCNnz+JoGOAL4AutGaMYlqqpreejpUBgBMDuYhfGGWuflazrIKSrgenhm+WbkBaVqFVkIlOc1BSQlpMRx9IMkItfWMWXmJbcW2U6DxCCgwTtDwANygoFJQcFRyAGYoYFQIACJoKACiZFQAtoqIY1l08HI7AOabZjMIb5-fIgVVxQAD8dAu6G+AxAcAAngAHU6QjDYBQoJDQMhw86XG73R44OLfUDwpG49D4h67AAKaAkMAAPAAVBBUAAeeygSBWKKpjwAfFhcHEEAAfDgAClZHK5PIp11u1MQoNwzJwACJvBqEggDPqUXS4AyWZrgVUdQLRXQoFRiPsAJRbWGI5GXI0mmWcxTylHihAUblUA47KhIIXYHDM0Wyn0rHAo0WqvlKx4epnqqAUO68ORxIXKOLOsmnABq5CkSHTwsN9KZJYgB2QlwFoAA9G2ECWEOWyJXq5HRWLcFqsjr-ZrtawEKPmMZx8PJ2Pp7PDEYNSu-EZ56L253F6uqBuZ34cguR1OT40z5vrzuJ4ez0WQKBILBEMQ6L3+3XhUvmMeh7jh2bJyHIEByAAhHuCAALTwQhiFIchyFCgAfhhmFoTBzKugwQH0AgUgrFAECIMsMBSB8UA8LcXYQF2eH0Ie87+ixZ7+oGSDBqGSD0KAQA)